# matching spaces in html <img> tag (regex)

Tags: html, regex

I have a bunch of html files where the filename in the img tag contains whitespaces ().
I need to replace whitespaces with underscores (_) in a text editor.
I am using this regular expression:

```
(?<=\/img\/)(\s)(?=.png")
```

but it doesn't work!
Here an example with expected result:

```
<img src="./img/setup3oval 7  1.png"/>
```

expected result:

```
<img src="./img/setup3oval_7__1.png"/>
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and their respective expected outputs?

Comment: Be careful with regular expressions around HTML, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your regex matches `/img/ 1png"`, this is a) between `/img/` and `.png`  there can only be a space, nothing else b) you use `.` instead of `\.`. Useful: https://regex101.com/r/CFEW9j/1

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @Cath yes I have more than one space, and no (\s)+ doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitations imposed by the regular expressions, it's not possible to do what you're asking for using a regex in a single run. But you *can* do it partially:

```
(?<=src=")(.*?)\s+(.*?)(?=\.)
```

You've mentioned that you're making use of a text editor to run this regex. If you're using something like Notepad++, you should be able to click the replace button multiple times until you reach the expected result, replacing your text by `$1_$2`. It shouldn't be too much of a problem if your image file paths doesn't have too much whitespaces in between them.

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `(?<=src=")` - This is a positive look behind, used to match only strings that are preceeded by this pattern. I'm using the `src` property as a reference instead of the `<img>` tag.
- `(.*?)\s+(.*?)`- This matches any whitespaces between two blocks of text. I've used lazy quantifiers to avoid wrong matches. I've also wrapped these blocks on capturing groups to use them on substitution.
- `(?=\.)` - This is a positive lookahead. The text will match until it reaches a dot character, literally. That is, assuming that there won't be any other dots on the line. You should change this assertion if that's not the case.

**Demonstration:** [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kdPXfN/2)

I've also tested this regex on Notepad++, hitting the substitution button multiple times. The expected results were achieved.

Comment: Big up for Pedro! Thank you very very much! I hope I will have the chance to help you back one day! I am using sublime text and it works great!